# Converting DateTime results in IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Time =(DateTime) AllQuestionsPresented.TryParse(dr["Time"].ToString());
```

Where `dr` is a SqlReader.

I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` and I don't know why. Here is the TryParse function:

```
public static DateTime? TryParse(string text)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out date))
    {
        return date;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I get that exception and how could i get rid of it?!

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Do you check `dr` isn't null before this line?

Comment: You have several operations happening on a single line of code. For debugging purposes, break the code down into its parts so that you can see which specific part is throwing the exception.

Comment: The message simply says : "Time"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might mean that it can't be found in reader. Does `dr` have column with name "Time"?